# How to fix CPlattformView.class NullPointerExcetion in Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Currently working on my first Java project since years.

The weird thing: If I run my code without debugger, it runs smoothly. However, once I run it using the debugger, I get a NullPointerExcetion and CPlattformView.class is tried to be opened in the editor showing "Source not found".

I have no idea, where this exception is being thrown. Breakpoint window shows the exception but no source file and line number.

Again, this only happens in debug mode.

Comment: Still, what about posting the exception stack trace? Besides: are you using a recent version of eclipse; and all your tooling around that is in at good versions too, everything well maintained? (just saying that debugging something like this can be hard; so you simply want to start on well-defined ground; versus trying to revive tools that you last touched years ago).

Comment: Yep, freshly downloaded and installed version of Ecplise on Mac using the Java Setup. Where can I see/print the stackstrace of the NullPointerException in Ecplise?

Comment: Normally such things should show up in the "console", so go "window", "show view", "console".